# C++ Inheritance: Calling constructor w/ args

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I'm trying to invoke my parent class's constructor that has arguments, in my child class's constructor with arguments, but I get a compiler error "expected primary expression before ...".
This is what I have:

```
class Ship {
    private:
        string shipName;
        int yearBuilt;
    public:
        Ship();
        Ship(string name, int year);
};
class CruiseShip: public Ship {
    private:
        int maxPeople;
    public:
        CruiseShip()
        : Ship() {
            maxPeople = 100;
        }
        CruiseShip(int m)
        : Ship(string name, int year) {
            maxPeople = m;
        }
};
Ship::Ship() {
    shipName = "Generic";
    yearBuilt = 1900;
}
Ship::Ship(string name, int year) {
    shipName = name;
    yearBuilt = year;
}
```

And this is the specific piece of code I'm having trouble with:

```
    CruiseShip(int m)
    : Ship(string name, int year) {
        maxPeople = m;
    }
```

My goal is to be able to create an object, CruiseShip c1 with 3 arguments that set the name,year, & max people.
I've been reading online and it tells me that this should be ok, but I'm obviously doing something wrong. I'd appreciate any input, thanks!

Comment: where are name and year defined?

Comment: I suggest using a constructor initializer list for your other members.

Comment: The assignment stated that name and year will be user defined in main, sorry this is only snippets of my code so I didn't give useless information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass parameters to parent class constructor like this:

```
CruiseShip(int m, string name, int year): Ship(name, year), maxPeople(m) {}
```

Better, you should set `maxPeople` to `m` in the initializer list.

Comment: You can also initialize `maxPeople` in the initializer list.  Cleaner that way IMO...

Comment: What would that look like to use maxPeople in the initializer list?                                                                 Edit: Thanks again, you guys are right, that's much cleaner!